# modification in streams app regarding data format conversion to json for a kafka pipeline

Tags: json, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

``i'm designing a pipeline where i have a producer publishing random sentences to a input kafka topic. Next, there is my windowed word count streams application which fetches the input data and performs manipulations on them and gets the windowed word count (Tumbling window of 5).
**Problem** **here** **is**
the output viewed through consumer console in output topic is as follows:
abc 1
abc 2
stack 1
overflow 2
overflow 3
... and so on

output format i want:

{"word": "abc", "count": 1}

now i need to send this to elasticsearch using kafka connect. everything else is working. there is just a serialization error because elasticsearch accepts data in json format.

So**i want the output data in json format after my streams has done manipulation on it** How do i achieve it. i'm stuck completely. i need to do conversion in streams application itself. Attaching streams app below for changes. please help.

```
KStream<String, String> initialstream = builder.stream("TextLinesTopic", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));

KStream<String, String> Tstream = initialstream.flatMapValues(value -> Arrays.asList(value.toLowerCase().split("\\W+")));

KGroupedStream<String, String> TgroupedStream = Tstream
.groupBy((key, word) -> word, Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));

KTable<Windowed<String>, Long> Ttable = TgroupedStream
                .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(5)))
                .count();

Ttable
                .toStream()
                .selectKey((key, word) -> key.key())
                .to("pipeoutput", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()));
```

Comment: i did mapping of my key value pair to the format i needed as follows:


.map((key, value) -> KeyValue.pair("{ \"word\": \""+key+"\",", "\"count\": \""+ value +"\" }"))
.to("molecule", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));

that's fine i guess, but when i'm using kafka connect it still shows me serialization error. 
i mean while producing this data am i going wrong. because my key and value converter in connect properties file is jsonConverter. (Should it be storage.StringConverter?) or am i deserializing in wrong way (should i use json serde?) if yes how?

Comment: If you want JSON format, you need to write proper JSON, what means you need to store the JSON either in the key OR the value -- atm, you split your Jsaon across both, ie, your key is `{"work": "someKey",` (this is not valid JSON) and your value is `"count": "someValue"}` (also not valid JSON). Only the concatenation of both key and value would be in valid JSON though.

Comment: I will depend on your connector if you need to put the data into the key or the value, for example `map((k,v) -> KeyValue.pair(null, /*put your full JSON here*/))`, that will give you a valid JSON in the value: `{"work": "somekey", "count", "someValue"}`. Not sure if using `String` will work (I assume yes); if not, you might need to put a proper `Json` object into the value and use a corresponding `JsonSerde` instead of `StringSerde`. -- Last, instead of putting `null` into the key, you might want to keep the key to preserve partitioning: `map((k,v) -> KeyValue.pair(k, /*full JSON*/))`

Comment: Not sure why you unaccepted my answer, but ^this is what my answer intends for you to do. Also worth pointing out that I'm not sure the Elasticsearch sink accepts null keys

Comment: Updated one, please check it out.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64700833/i-have-a-kafka-pipeline-json-problem-update-for-kafka-connect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the `.to()`, you need to `.map()` your key,value pair into your expected output that matches the format you wish to send to your downstream consumers

You also would have to change the Produced.with value serde not to be a Long since you'd be writing a JSON String

Comment: yeah this is right way to go, but refer my above link for further things in it. there's more to it.